# Can the Weyl algebra be free over its invariant subalgebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, invariant-theory, weyl-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of zero characteristic, let $P_n$ denote the polynomial algebra in $n$ indeterminates, and let $G$ be a finite group of linear automorphisms. Then, by Chevalley-Shephard-Todd (C-S-T) Theorem, $P_n^G \simeq P_n$ if and only if $G$ is a pseudo-reflection group.

A natural generalization of the question addressed by the (C-S-T) theorem is the following: let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, and $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms. When we have $A^G \simeq A$?

A famous result in this direction is the *rigidity* of the Weyl algebras, due to Alev and Polo (the paper can be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870885710225)): if $G$ is an arbitrary finite group of automorphisms of the Weyl algebra $A_n$, then $A_n^G \simeq A_n$ if and only if $G$ is trivial.

There many other equivalent conditions for the invariant algebra $P_n^G$ to be polynomial (see for instance [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459567/list-of-equivalent-conditions-for-the-invariant-subalgebra-to-be-polynomial))

In particular: $P_n^G$ is polynomial if and only if $P_n$ is a finitely generated free $P_n^G$-module.

I'm interested in the analogous question for the Weyl algebras:

**Question:** Let $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms of $A_n$. Can $A_n$ be a free finitely generated (left) $A_n^G$-module?

I am interested in particular in the case of $G$ being the symmetric group $S_n$ with the canonical action.

There is a partial positive result in this direction: for *any* $G$, $A_n$ is a finitely generated projective left $A_n^G$-module